# Why PHP repeatedly being executed while in cronjob?

Tags: php, cron, repeat

I setup a cronjob at CentOS 6.4 (final) server (with PHP 5.5.9 and Apache httpd 2.4.4) installed):

```
30 15 * * * wget "http://10.15.1.2/calc.php" -O /dev/null
```

**calc.php** ftps several servers to download serveral logs files (using PHP built-in ftp functions), insert log records in logfiles into a single temp table, then count different-date log records, lastly insert counted results into another summary table. It's a very simple program.

**calc.php** starts at 15:30 and end at 15:46 (calc.php will write the time to log). When I check the log, **I find calc.php is being executed again at 15:45.** (almost when first-run near ends.) I've double check my calc.php. In the main logic, I doesn't use any loop statements, e.g. while, do-while, or  for, etc. All tasks mentioned above are written as functions in same program file. I run same url on browser many times, they all work normally.

So what could be the reason that causes repeated execution while running in cron job?

---

**Here's the main logic part** (Note: *myxxxx()* are my own simple display-message functions. *USEARRAY_MODE* and *TESTINSTMP_MODE* aren't defined while running) :

```
    myassess("Being-calcuated logfile list=\n".xpr($srclog_fn_list));

    if (defined('USEARRAY_MODE')) {

        // Insert outer srclog into temp array

       if (false === ($srclog_calc_date = insert_srclog_to_array($srclog_get_date, $srclog_dir, $srclog_delta_days, $srclog_fn_list, $logtmp_sfile, $logtmp_dfile, $logtmp_result))) {
            myerror("Insert outer srclog  to temp array has problem!");
            exit;
       }
       myassess("Actually calculated date = $srclog_calc_date.");

        // If testinstemp mode, we stop here without doing statistics

        if (defined('TESTINSTMP_MODE')) {
            myinfo("Skipping statistics in testinstmp mode.");
            exit;
        }

        // Do statistics and then insert into summary table

        $total_cnt_list = do_statistics_from_array($_cnt_g2s_array, $userlist_tempfile, $rule_file, $srclog_calc_date, $logtmp_result);

    } else { // use table

        // Insert outer srclog 入 temp array

        if (false === ($srclog_calc_date = insert_srclog_to_table($srclog_get_date, $srclog_dir, $srclog_delta_days, $srclog_fn_list))) {
            myerror("Insert outer srclog to temp table has problem!");
            exit;
        }
        myassess("Actually calculated date = $srclog_calc_date.");

        // If testinstemp mode, we stop here without doing statistics

        if (defined('TESTINSTMP_MODE')) {
            myinfo("Skipping statistics in testinstmp mode.");
            exit;
        }

        // Do statistics and then insert into summary table

        $total_cnt_list = do_statistics_from_table($_cnt_g2s_array, $userlist_tempfile, $rule_file, $srclog_calc_date);

    }
    if (false === $total_cnt_list)
        myerror("Calculate/Write outer summary has problem!");
    else {
        myinfo("Outer srclog actually calculated date = $srclog_calc_date.");
        myinfo("Total summary count = ".array_sum($total_cnt_list));
        myinfo("Insert-ok summary count = ".$total_cnt_list[0]);
        myinfo("!!!Insert-fail summary count = ".$total_cnt_list[1]);
    }
    @mysql_close($wk_dbconn);
    @oci_close($uodb_conn);

myinfo("### Running end at ".date(LOG_DATEFORMAT1).".");
myinfo("### total exectution time：".elapsed_time($_my_start_time, microtime(true)));
    myinfo("############ END program ############");

    exit;
```

Comment: Yes! I check them twice. I'm sure only one cron job by issuing `crontab -l | grep "calc.php"` command to check it. I've checked cronjob lists of multiple constantly-used accounts on this server (including root account).

Comment: Have you tried to restart cron?

Comment: No! I'll try restart it.